# How to get json array name if match with condition

Tags: java, android, json, date

I'm first storing JSON array "date" in arratstring and match my date with list if is match then show "title" name of that date  after this line    `if (Vacation_Date.contains(mydate)) {`

I want to print only that value which is match that date title name in textview what will I do help me please

```
static ArrayList<Long> Vacation_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
static ArrayList<String> Vacation_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Vacation_Date = new ArrayList<String>();
         JSONObject json3 = new JSONObject(str2);
        status = json3.getString("status");
        if (status.equals("1")) {
        JSONArray school = json3.getJSONArray("data");
        for (int k = 0; k < school.length(); k++) {
            JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) school.getJSONObject(k);
            Vacation_ID.add((long) k);  
                    Vacation_Date.add(jb.getString("date"));
            }
        }
```

Strong array "date" from json file  in `Vacation_Date`. Now i m comparing my date with Vacation_Date and check my date if exist in Vacation_Date and show its title name in textview.

```
if (Vacation_Date.contains(mydate))
```

//now what i do to show title name of match date

```
textview.settext ("title name of match date")'
 }
```

JSON

```
{"status":1,
"data":
[
    {"id":"1",
    "title":"abc",
    "date":"2013-09-29"},

    {"id":"2",
    "title":"abc1",
    "date":"2013-09-25"},

    {"id":"3",
    "title":"abc",
    "date":"2013-10-05"},

    {"id":"4",
    "title":"abc1",
    "date":"2013-09-27"}
]
}
```

Comment: can you format your code.

Comment: value of mydate is"2013-09-25" so how i will show textview only title of date"2013-09-25" from json file

Comment: what is the problem in displaying it in textview. problem in parsing?

Comment: i want to show in textview only that title which match with mydate

Comment: if (Vacation_Date.contains(mydate))  where mydate="2013-09-25" is trute now i want to print in textview only the name of match date which is "abc1" in json file

Comment: no parsingis perfectly only problem is forloop and show selected value in textview if condition is true at this line
if (Vacation_Date.contains(mydate))   show only that date "title"

Comment: print only that"title in textview which match with mydate

Comment: @smartguy: Houcine has already replied and it should work. It took me some minutes to actually understand the problem. Just an advice, moving forward try to explain the problem little bit clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's suppose that you want to display the title when the date is equal to : 2013-10-05, so create a method to retreive the title by searching it in the `jsonArray` with the condition on the date attribute :

```
public String getTitleForDate(String searchDate) {
    for ( int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        JSONObject json = array.getJSONObject(i);
        String date = json.optString("date");
        if(date != null && searchDate.equals(date)) {
            return json.optString("title");
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and then display the title in the `TextView` like this :

```
if(Vacation_Date.contains(mydate)) {
String title = getTitleForDate(mydate); // i.e : in the case of mydate = "2013-10-05", it will return "abc" title
if(title != null)
    yourTextView.setText(title);
}
```

Comment: wherei place function inside this if statement
if (Vacation_Date.contains(mydate))

Comment: tell me with respect to my code tell me what i do after this line
if (Vacation_Date.contains(mydate))  
show match date title value in textview? i change my code above check

Comment: @smartguy: after your if condition place this code and in the method pass the date object. String title = getTitleForDate("2013-10-05"); // it will return "abc" title
if(title != null)
    yourTextView.setText(title);

Comment: as @Vinothbabu said , the method will be declared in your activity, and the code of displaying the title in the textView , add it after your Condition of Vacation_Date.contains(mydate); see my edits